# How do you run multiple powershell commands in c# with strings?

Tags: c#, powershell

I used to run this program through a .Bat file.  I was trying to see if I could do this through strings instead.  This one is suppose to turn off hibernation, but won't do it this way, and did work the old way.

The old code:

```
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command "".\power\powercfg.bat""";
```

The New code:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add(" @echo off");
        strings.Add("set drive =% cd:~0,3 %");
        strings.Add("powercfg.exe - x - hibernate - timeout - dc 0");


        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count(); i++) { 
            var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        newProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
        newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command " + strings[i];
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Power Config Settings Applied Successfully - Now Your PC Won't hibernate");
     }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `-executionpolicy unrestricted` be `set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy unrestricted`?

Comment: The set-executionpolicy doesn't work.  I just tried that with the old commands, just in case.  Thank you for the input